# Comparing Multi-level Meta-regression to Network Meta-Analysis for Dose-response Project

Tags: meta-analysis, meta-regression, metafor, network-meta-analysis, dose-response

I am planning a meta-analysis to examine the average change in a continuous variable over time within my area of research. To be able to meta-analyze this continuous relationship, I've typically performed a multi-level meta-regression with the following structure where yi = standardized mean change for a given outcome within a group within a study, vi = the sampling variances, and time = intervention duration:

```
metafor::rma.mv(yi,vi,
mods= ~time,
random = list(~time|study,~1|group,~1|es.id),
struct = "GEN",
method = "REML"
dfs = "contain",
test = "t")%>%
robust(cluster=study, clubSandwich=TRUE)
```

From here, I would explore additional models that evaluate the influence of various interacting moderators:

```
metafor::rma.mv(yi,vi,
mods= ~time * moderator,
random = list(~time * moderator|study,~1|group,~1|es.id),
struct = "GEN",
method = "REML"
dfs = "contain",
test = "t")%>%
robust(cluster=study, clubSandwich=TRUE)
```

However, someone has mentioned to me that a dose-response network meta-analysis may be a [better option](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MBNMAdose/index.html). Frankly, I am not super familiar with those approaches but from what [I've gathered](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33448252/), they are fitting dose-response relationships at each one of the "nodes" in the network. To me, this seems applicable when you have clearly categorical interacting moderators, whereas most of what I am interested in are continuous.

Open to hearing any pros / cons of each of these approaches from more experienced users and pointing out any of my misconceptions.